# Synchronized data commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a JAVA code,

```
synchronized (this.getClass()) 
{
    System.out.println("stsrt");
    certRequest.setRequestNbr(
        generateRequestNumber(
            certInsuranceRequestAddRq.getAccountInfo().getAccountNumberId()));
    System.out.println("outside funcvtion"+certRequest.getRequestNbr());
    reqId = Utils.getUniqueId();
    certRequest.setRequestId(reqId);
    System.out.println(reqId);
    ItemIdInfo itemIdInfo = new ItemIdInfo();
    itemIdInfo.setInsurerId(certRequest.getRequestId());
    certRequest.setItemIdInfo(itemIdInfo);
    dao.insert(certRequest);
    addAccountRel();
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

now suppose I get calls from two threads , for this code. I want that my  `dao.insert(certRequest);`
should be committed before my second thread comes. I am new to Spring and Hibernate. Could anyone please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: Make a explicit call to commit methods via Hibernate `flush` and `clear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate will respect the order of your calls to insert method, but if you want to read the committed value with a second thread, you may have to flush the session :

```
getCurrentSession().flush()
```

Comment: Can I know the reason behind your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a separate business need for 2 threads they are not really needed here. You can have this method at your `Service` tier demarcated as `@Transactional`. The default `Propagation`/`Isolation` semantics (supposing you have setup a Spring Hibernate Transaction Manager) will ensure your second `insert` not to execute until the first one completes (or is rolledback) as part of this transactional unit.

Comment: There is a seperate business need. Also my issue is, the data for first insert() isn't committed, and before reading the same database table again, by the second thread.